# Unbound class path variable java android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

What does the meaning of Unbound Class Path variable on Eclipse? I got the error and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: clean your project first

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> *What does the meaning of Unbound Class Path variable on Eclipse?*

It's a warning message that says, a [classpath variable](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-classpath-variables.htm) is no longer valid.

> *I got the error and don't know how to fix it.*

I'm sure you also get a description of which varible was unbound.

Goto Eclipe -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables

Check if the said variable/jar file is present and add/edit if required.

Comment: Just note if you checked out the project from a repository, check the documentation if there are any classpath variables referenced. Its a common practice to avoid hard referencing e.g. say programmer A might save all jar files in C:, but programmer B might want to keep it on D: and so on.

Comment: For other versions of Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables

Answer (score 5):

In one of the projects I just created, the M2_REPO classpath variable was not defined. Defining the M2_REPO (not M2_Repo, which is what I had) variable fixed the error.

- m

Answer (score 3):

**Cause**

Variable specified in .classpath not found.

**Resolution**

Goto Eclipe -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables

Check if the specified variable is available.

If not , Add it along with the expected value.