# How can I really get rid of a eclipse classpath variable

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

In an eclipse project there was once the classpath variable JAVA_TOOLS (pointing somewhere to the Java  installation). I don't need the variable anymore, so I removed it from the project, but eclipse still complains

```
Unbound classpath variable: 'JAVA_TOOLS' in project '...'
```

and refuses to do anything. I've removed the variable also from eclipse and cleaned the project. The command `find . -type f | xargs grep JAVA_TOOLS` returns no matches, so I have no idea where the reference may still exist.

Comment: Possibly in the .classpath file.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185190/unbound-class-path-variable-java-android-eclipse-problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185190/unbound-class-path-variable-java-android-eclipse-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tried everything else (including refresh, eclipse restart with `--clean`, ...) I finally came to the trivial idea to close and reopen the project. It helped...

So it looks like such things get cached somewhere outside of the project directory.

Comment: I had build-path errors randomly appear, lying to me about my M2_REPO classpath variable being unbound, and cleaning and rebuilding didn't work.  Closing and reopening the projects before cleaning and building again did.  Thanks.  :)